# z-index layer and jquery animations with the Cycle plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, z-index, cycle, layer

I'm using a Jquery plugin, Cycle, and want an image button to be on top of the animations. The images in the animation scroll in one side and out the other. No matter what I do, the button is always layered UNDER the animated images. Z-index is ignored in all browsers. 
How do I put it on TOP on the animation?

Comment: Do you have some code you could show? z-index only applies to positioned elements: (absolute, relative or fixed). Is it possible you haven't set a position css on the image or its parent?

Comment: Ah, I needed to add a position attribute to the image button's css to get the z-index to be recognized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `z-index` property requires an element to have either `position:relative` or `position:absolute` to have any effect. Is this the case?